# xsl T datetime operation error in openerp

Tags: xslt, datetime, odoo

I tried to add hour in datetime but it return this error: "XPath evaluation returned no result."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:import href="../../base/report/corporate_defaults.xsl" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:call-template name="rml" />
<xsl:variable name="dT" as="xs:dateTime"  
  select="xs:dateTime('1995-04-21T00:47:00')"/>
<xsl:variable name="dTD1" as="xs:dayTimeDuration" 
  select="xs:dayTimeDuration('P5DT9H23M12S')"/>
</xsl:template>

<... body .. >

                    <xsl:value-of select="($dT)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="($dTD1)"/>
```

Best Regards,

Comment: How confident are you that your OpenERP software supports XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that:

```
<xsl:value-of select="($dT)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="($dTD1)"/>
```

Can be changed to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$dT"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$dTD1"/>
```

Comment: Yes, but that's hardly going to change anything, is it?

Comment: Yes, but if i remove this line xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ,  <xsl:value-of select="($dT + $dTD1)"/> give me NaN result

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the error to say that the variables $dT and $dTD1 are out of scope. They are declared inside a template rule, and referenced outside that template rule.